# MAC Address in TextField

Tags: java, swing, mac-address, ipconfig

Hello I am trying to create a GUI with a simple button to refresh the information in 3 textfields.

IP Address
Host Name
MAC Address

of the fields above i have the first 2 sorted they work but i cant work out how to get the last one working.

On my GUI the text fields contain no code, i am using the code of the button to set the text in these fields.

The code is as follows.

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testforensicsapp;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 *
 * @author jblacklock
 */
public class ForensicsGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ForensicsGui
     */
    public ForensicsGui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane2 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTabbedPane3 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTabbedPane8 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane2 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane3 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jTabbedPane2.addTab("tab1", jButton1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 841, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 292, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane3.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        jButton2.setText("X");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Start / Refresh");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextPane1.setEditable(false);
        jTextPane1.setText("IP Address");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        jTextPane2.setText("Host Name");
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextPane2);

        jTextPane3.setText("MAC Address");
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextPane3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 116, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 102, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane3)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 102, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(627, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(191, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane8.addTab("Computer Information", jPanel2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 904, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 888, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 392, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                           

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        InetAddress ip;
        try {

            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            jTextField2.setText(ip.getHostAddress());

            java.net.InetAddress localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            jTextField1.setText(localMachine.getHostName());

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            jTextField3.setText(.getHardwareAddress());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ForensicsGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ForensicsGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ForensicsGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ForensicsGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ForensicsGui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane3;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static class ComponentMover {

        public ComponentMover() {
        }
    }

    private static class BorderLayout {

        public BorderLayout() {
        }
    }
}
```

i cant figure out where i am going wrong with this and any help would be greatly appreciated at this stage as it is taking a lot longer to complete.

this code is to get the local, IP, Mac and hostname of my machine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and your question is not clear

Comment: Awesome! It looks like a GUI generated by JBuidler. I'm out , sorry.

Comment: Sorry just edited it, I did the GUI in design view, but it is literally just the MAC Address, wont show in the text-field i just get an error and i have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Comment: *"i just get an error"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 and above you could use this approach (and [commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)) -
Replace these two lines (from your question) -

```
byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
jTextField3.setText(.getHardwareAddress());
```

with these lines -

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface
      .getNetworkInterfaces(); // to actually make this work
byte[] mac = null;
while (nics.hasMoreElements()) {
  NetworkInterface ni = nics.nextElement();
  if (ni != null && ni.getHardwareAddress() != null) { // Be sure.
    mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
    break;
  }
}
// https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html
if (mac != null) {
  jTextField3.setText(Hex.encodeHexString(mac));
}
```

And it works on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for your information but I am still not sure on how to implement this? i do however have another project which grabs the IP, MAC and host name and just displays it in the output with no GUI. is it possible to drag the information from that separate projects output and set the text in my textfield and would it be easier or just make things more complicated? if it would be easier i can edit my post to show that code for my other project as well.

Comment: @user3080543 Edited my answer but, I'm replacing your two lines `byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress(); jTextField3.setText(.getHardwareAddress());` and I tested it.